# Print list inside two other lists in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Here is my list:

```
index = [['you', ['http://you.com', 'http://you.org']], ['me', ['http://me.org']]]
```

How can I print a list that inside of the 'you' list?

I have tried to do this way:

```
>>>print index[0]
```

but it's printing out full 'you' list:

```
['you', ['http://you.com', 'http://you.org']]
```

and the output I need is:

```
['http://you.com', 'http://you.org']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a list within a list, so you need to specify a second index ie

```
print index[0][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

As `index[0]` returns the first item in `index`, `index[0][1]` will return the second item within the first item:

```
>>> index = [['you', ['http://you.com', 'http://you.org']], ['me', ['http://me.org']]]
>>> index[0]
['you', ['http://you.com', 'http://you.org']]
>>> index[0][1]
['http://you.com', 'http://you.org']
```

In addition, if you have the time, spend some of it getting familiar with [python data structures](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). You won't regret it.